# If $0 \in W(A)\mathop \Rightarrow \limits^? W(A) = \left\{ {{x^*}Ax:x \in {C^n},{x^*}x \le 1} \right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ and $W(A)$ be numerical range of $A$.

Suppose $0\in W(A)$.

Why does $W(A) = \left\{ {{x^*}Ax:x \in {C^n},{x^*}x \le 1} \right\}$?

Comment: It may help that, without loss of generality, $A$ can be taken to be upper-triangular.

Comment: $W(A)$ is convex.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel - Please more guide.

Comment: Where are you stuck? If you know that it is convex, it's nothing more than just using definitions of the numerical range and the convex set.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel - Thanks.